# Exporting selected features with predefined path to data and their name in QGIS with Python

Tags: pyqgis, export, path

I am trying to export selected data with predefined path where the data should be saved and how they should be named. Currently in my script I use the direct path and name, but I need to automate this because I have several data and have to export them several times with different selection. My current line is as follow:

```
writer = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layer,r"Z:/"'K4_System_12x10_6 blau',"utf-8", onlySelected=True)
```

I have specified the path and names that I would like to use, but I do not know to use them correctly in the above mentioned line, so that the function writer use them to name my exported features.

```
path = r"Z:/"
name = "K4"
fieldname1 = 'System'
SystemA = '12x10_6 blau'
```

Comment: Is that writer line working as it is?

Comment: Yes, why? Is there something wrong with the writer line? I only shortened the path in my post  to: r"Z:/" because the path which I am using is very long...

Comment: Ok. Because I dont know how a working line looks like. I think using [string format](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_format.asp) and [os.path.join](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-os-path-join-method/) to create the new one  is probably a good idea